# Need to compute column total in SAS and use it as input to calculate another column

Tags: sas

```
Data IV_SAS;
   set IV;
   Total_Loans=Goods+Bads;
   Dist_Loans=Total_Loans/sum(Total_Loans));
   Dist_Goods=Goods/Sum(Goods);
   Dist_Bads=Bads/Sum(Bads);
   Difference=Dist_Goods-Dist_Bads;
   WOE=log10(Dist_goods/Dist_Bads);
   IV=WOE*Difference;
run;
```

I am facing issues in calculating sum of (Total Loans),its calculating Row total instead of column total.

Comment: Yes, functions operate on a row. Use proc means/summary/univariate to create a column total.

Answer (score 0):

That's how Base SAS works - it operates on row level in the data step.

You would want to use `PROC MEANS` or `PROC TABULATE` or similar proc and find the column total there, then merge that on (or combine in another method).

For example:

```
proc means data=sashelp.class;
  var age height weight;
  output out=class_means sum(age)=age_sum sum(height)=height_sum sum(weight)=weight_Sum;
run;

data class;
  if _n_=1 then set class_means;
  set sashelp.class;
  age_prop = age/age_sum;
  height_prop = height/height_sum;
  weight_prop = weight/weight_Sum;
run;
```

Alternately, use `SAS/IML` or `PROC SQL`, both of which will operate on the column level when asked inline (though I think the above solution is likely superior in speed to both due to lower overhead).

Answer (score 0):

```
    data a;
   input goods  bads;
   datalines;
36945   33337
23820   21761
26990   24647
33195   30299
43755   39014
46100   41100
89765   79978
25940   23508
35940   32506
31840   28846
33430   30366
34480   31388
36640   33129
39640   35992
42490   38325
44240   40075
42840   38840
49690   44936
69190   64740
;
run;

proc sql;
create table b as 
      select goods,bads,
            sum(goods,bads) as Total_Loans format=dollar10.,
            sum(goods)as Column_goods_tot format=dollar10. ,
             sum(bads) as Column_bads_tot format=dollar10. ,
             sum(calculated Column_goods_tot, calculated Column_bads_tot) as Column_Total_Loans format=dollar10. ,
        (calculated Total_Loans/calculated Column_Total_Loans) as Dist_Loans 
/*add more code to calculate Dist_Goods, Dist_Bads, etc..*/
      from a;
quit;


/*Column totals only*/
proc sql;
create table c as 

            select 
            sum(goods)as Column_goods_tot format=dollar10. ,
             sum(bads) as Column_bads_tot format=dollar10. ,
             sum(calculated Column_goods_tot, calculated Column_bads_tot) as Column_Total_Loans format=dollar12. 

      from a;
quit;
```